# How to have two vue props alter each other

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to have 2 props directly affect each other and cannot figure out how to do it.

I have 3 props in total:

- startDate
- endDate
- duration

Where startDate and endDate are set then the difference between the date will set the duration.

However, if duration is altered then it will either increase or decrease the endDate by adding the duration to the startDate

I have tried using watched properties on both but can not figure out how to get them to fire. Can anyone point me to a relevant example or provide a suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Any code maybe ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can trap any looping by putting a Computed Setter in the path, and only do the update via this setter.

See [Computed Setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

```js
computed: {
  endDateComputed: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.endDate
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      if (newValue !== this.endDate) {
        this.endDate = newValue
      }
    }
  }
}
```